# 五女二男 read as "ごじょになん”？

Tags: translation

In がばいばあちゃん, the phrase 五女二男 crops up. Given the compact nature of the expression, I'm assuming 男 and 女 are read with their alternate readings なん and じょ respectively while the numbers remain unchanged. However, this is the first time I've encountered a phrase of this kind, hence my question. The full sentence is as follows.

> 昭和十七年（一九四二年）、戦中に夫を亡くし、以来、厳しい戦後を佐賀大学とその附属小中学校の掃除婦をして、五女二男、合計七人の子供を育てて生き抜いてきた。

I translated this as:

> In the 17th year of Showa (1942) she lost her husband in the war, and afterwards during the harsh postwar period worked as a cleaning lady in the combined primary and middle school attached to Saga university, and having five girls and two boys, with a combined total of seven, she successfully brought up her children.

よろしくお願いします.

Comment: Do you include がばいばあちゃん in the total number of eight?

Comment: Sorry; I meant a total of seven. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 五女二男 read as "ごじょになん”？

Yes, ◯女◯男 is read as "◯じょ◯なん", you just fill the numbers of boys/girls in ◯ simply.

Answer (score 1):

I think "correct" reading is ごにょになん though I don't know how many Japanese actually care about it.

Comment: Can you point to a source?

Comment: For 男女, だんじょ is 漢音読み and なんにょ is 呉音読み.

Comment: Ok, so how does ごにょになん end up being the "correct" reading? Is there a special rule as to when to apply 呉音読み?

Comment: Because *basically* and *theoretically* a 漢字熟語 is supposed to be read in a consistent pronunciation system (I mean a dialect/language pronunciation system) unless that kind of reading has established as standard?

Comment: I think I get it. You're suppose read both as 漢音読み or 呉音読み, but you're not meant to mix the two unless that reading is recognised as an exception? That's what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. But じょ for 女 and なん for 男 are relatively more popular in counter-like 熟語 than にょ and だん and it makes things difficult.

Comment: Then, perhaps the tendency would be to say じょ and なん together, even if it is contrary to the rule you mentioned, so it might have become standard in its own right and would be the most likely reading if a Japanese person read that phrase automatically without thinking?

Comment: I don't know... I don't have any stats on it and haven't read any "authoritative" view on it, so I thought it was inevitable that somebody would say ごじょになん is "wrong" or sounds strange.